# Fgets progress - easier way?

Tags: php

I read a big text file ~500MB and want to get the progress during my read operations.

To do so I now count the lines the files has and then compare it to the ones I already read. This needs two complete iterations over the file. Is there an easier way using the filesize and fgets buffer size?

My current code looks like:

```
$lineTotal = 0;
while ((fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $lineTotal++;
}

rewind($handle);

$linesDone = 0;
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    progressBar($linesDone += 1, $lineTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on bytes rather than lines, but you can quickly get the total size of the file upfront with [`filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php):

```
$bytesTotal = filesize("input.txt")
```

Then, after you've opened the file, you can read each line and then get your [current position](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php) within the file, something like:

```
progressBar(0, $bytesTotal);
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    doSomethingWith($line, 'presumably');
    progressBar(ftell($handle), $bytesTotal);
}
```

There are caveats about the fact that PHP integers may not handle files over 2G but, since you specified your files are about 500M, that shouldn't be an immediate problem.

Comment: Thanks thats much better!